# How to fetch the List View Id through List Button

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, list-view, screen-flow

I created an LWC which has the Navigation Mixin method inside, so when I click on the button it should direct me to the case creation page. I call this lwc from the screen flow and I have created a list view button that calls the flow. I don't know how to get the id of the listview from the flow. I have a method to get object name from Id so if I pass the id of listview I can get the sobject type and then the object name